# Faster way to do a conditional sum from a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to see how many values in a nested dictionary are <= a value (rcEnterThreshold) subject to couple other simple conditions.  The nested dictionary has about 10 million values and its taking about 30 seconds to do the following:

```
numCandidateVars = sum(1 for f in reducedCosts 
                         for t in reducedCosts[f] 
                       if f!=t if reducedCosts[f][t][colGenLoopCounter] <= rcEnterThreshold 
                       if t not in EdgeDict[f])
```

Is there a modification I can make to this to speed it up significantly?  Should I scrap the use of dictionaries completely in favour of another data structure more suited?  Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you give an example dict? It's hard to read your one liner...

Comment: It would help illustrate your problem better with a sample input and expected output.

Comment: I did not provide input and desired output because the code works fine; it's just slow.  And in order to illustrate the speed problem, you would need a massive dataset.  I am more interested if anything is glaringly inefficient; such as a critical blatant flaw in approach, a mis-ordering of the conditions, etc

Comment: CodeReview.stackexchange.com might be a better place for a question like this.

Comment: One of the reasons we ask for sample input is that you are asking us to work out the structure of your *nested dictionary* by reading your one-liner. If you want help then it would be better not to expect us do this unnecessary work, just so we can understand your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get some speedup by iterating on the `items()` of your nested dictionaries, rather than just getting keys and indexing them each time. I doubt the speedup will be large since indexing is `O(1)`, but it might help some.

```
numCandidateVars = sum(1 for f, middle in reducedCosts.items() 
                         for t, inner in middle.items()
                         if f!=t
                         if inner[colGenLoopCounter] <= rcEnterThreshold 
                         if t not in EdgeDict[f])
```

I'll also echo Turksarama that having many `if` clauses in a single generator expression seems very weird. I've been using Python for years, and I didn't know until reading your code that such a thing was legal! A single `if` can test multiple conditions if you connect them with `and`. Unfortunately, switching to use `and` probably won't speed things up much (or at all) since it seems that multiple `if` clauses short circuit in exactly the same way `and` does.

It's possible the reordering your conditions could help performance, but since you haven't told us anything at all about the nature of your data, we have no possible way to judge which tests will be faster than others. I'd guess that the key test `f != t` is fast, but if those are complex types, even that might not be true. I'd guess the order is the best you can do already.

The one other place you might be able to speed things up is not actually in the code you've shown, but in `EdgeDict`. If it's values are containers that are not efficient to check membership in (such as lists), the last condition will be slow. You could speed it up by using a `set` or a `dict`, as those types have `O(1)` membership tests. If the values of `EdgeDict` are already of those types, then I don't have any further suggestions, other than maybe profiling the code and seeing what step is actually taking the most time.

Comment: EdgeDict value is an int

Comment: You're doing `t not in EdgeDict[f]`, so I'd expect `EdgeDict[f]` to be some kind of container. If the `not in` operator is slow for that container type, you might be able to speed up the code by changing the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

<del>You're looking for a length, so try len() rather than sum(), but other than that</del> we probably can't help you with just the information you've given us.  What data type is f? if it's integers then a list may be faster.  What is colGenLoopCounter?  Try also using one if statement with ands, with the one most likely to fail first.  This should let you shortcut.

Example:

```
numCandidateVars = sum(1 for f in reducedCosts 
                       for t in reducedCosts[f] 
                       if f!=t # this is suspicious, why is it here?
                       and reducedCosts[f][t][colGenLoopCounter] <= rcEnterThreshold 
                       and t not in EdgeDict[f])
```

Comment: You can't call `len` on a genexp, which is why the OP used sum.

Comment: I've never seen multiple `if` clauses in a generator expression either, but it appears they already do short-circuit (left to right, just like chained `and`s), so your only recommendation here may be meaningless.